# What are applications to sort plain integer arrays?

Tags: sorting, integers, quicksort, applications

A lot of research and engineering effort is put into finding fast methods
to sort an array of integers; e.g., Java's runtime library has highly-tuned
methods to sort arrays of each primitive type (see [java.util.DualPivotQuicksort](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java)).

What are real-world applications of these methods?
What are algorithms that build on plain integer sorting?

Let me clarify: I am not asking of applications of sorting per se, I am well aware that there is plenty of them. But it seems to me, most actually require to sort more complex data types with additional data.
Typically these objects/records are sorted with respect to some key field, which might well be an integer, but this is not quite the same as sorting only an array of plain integers.
In particular, sorting keys with auxiliary data would not be possible using the Java methods in java.util.DualPivotQuicksort.

Comment: One _reduces_ to plain integer sorting. ​ ​

Comment: @Paparazzi: He shows links to code that sorts an array of integers. Given that code, I can easily write code that will sort an array of objects with integer keys, but the code linked to sorts just integers. And its a reasonable question: Why would we care about the performance of code that can sort just integers, nothing else?

Comment: @gnasher729 Not how read the question.   Comments are not for discussion.

Comment: @RickyDemer I'd count an interesting reduction as a valid application, if it solves a practical problem. Were you thinking of a specific problem that is reduced to integer sorting?

Comment: Yes - "objects/records" "with respect to some" integer "key field" ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: How would that work, using integer sorting as a black box?

Comment: [Here's Python code for that](http://pastebin.com/V94HCZqC), although unless you've done Python before, there's probably at least one part of the syntax you don't understand. ​ ​

Comment: er, to make that valid Python, I should've written `def reduction(records):` instead of `reduction(records):`. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer OK, the code is terse, but the idea is clear. (Embarrassed that I did not see this method immediately.) Although the scope is limited (the blowup of the domain can hurt ...), I think it is an acceptable answer. Would you like to write it up?